# Why is webassembly needed?

Tags: webassembly

Why do browsers need webassembly in order to run programs compiled from non-javascript languages? Specifically, why can't x86 assembly be used instead?

I googled around but couldn't find any good info on this.

Maybe it has something to do with interoperability with JavaScript, including HTML5 and browser APIs? Is it WASM's ability to call and be called by JavaScript that makes it useful in a browser?

Comment: Your phone probably doesn't have an x86 chip. You tablet either. Watch, connected eyeware, WiFi shoes same. Why would the (extremely complex) x86 instruction set be a good choice?

Comment: @Mat that's not the point. I'm not saying only use x86, you would have to include ARMv6 as well, then just about all devices are covered. It would be a good choice because it already exists and it's 2x faster

Comment: Is it that bad to have 2 assembly languages supported instead of just one?

Comment: One purpose-built format rather than emulating two completely different ISAs that weren't designed for it.

Comment: Weren't designed for what? What is webassembly designed to do different than x86? (to rephrase my original question)

Comment: A clearer question might be "what problem does webassembly solve?"

Comment: I see the question has been closed for being opinion-based, but I was hoping there was an official reason for creating WASM. Or a problem that just couldn't be solved with existing assembly languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:
WebAssembly is fast, safe, portable, and part of the open Web platform.
Using the advantage of strongly typed languages like Go, Rust, ... (compiler can detect many errors at compile time)
Portable target for compilation of high-level languages
Available on a wide range of platforms including mobile and IoT (not just x86)
Efficient and fast (near-native performance, precompiled: relative to JavaScript)
Size-efficient and load-time-efficient binary format
Memory-safe
Sandboxed execution environment
Non-web embeddings
Accessible from JavaScript, integrate well with the existing Web platform
Integrating with the Web ecosystem
Leveraging Web APIs
Supporting the Web’s security model
Preserving the Web’s portability
Designing in room for evolutionary development

---

### Efficient and fast

The Wasm stack machine is designed to be encoded in a size- and load-time-efficient binary format. WebAssembly aims to execute at native speed by taking advantage of common hardware capabilities available on a **wide range of platforms**.

### Safe

WebAssembly describes a **memory-safe, sandboxed execution environment** that may even be implemented inside existing JavaScript virtual machines. When embedded in the web, WebAssembly will enforce the same-origin and permissions security policies of the browser.

### Open and debuggable

WebAssembly is designed to be pretty-printed in a textual format for debugging, testing, experimenting, optimizing, learning, teaching, and writing programs by hand. The textual format will be used when viewing the source of Wasm modules on the web.

### Part of the open web platform

WebAssembly is designed to maintain the versionless, feature-tested, and backwards-compatible nature of the web. WebAssembly modules will be able to call into and out of the JavaScript context and access browser functionality through the same Web APIs accessible from JavaScript. WebAssembly also supports non-web embeddings.

---

Refs:
[Design Rationale](https://webassembly.org/docs/rationale/)
[WebAssembly High-Level Goals](https://webassembly.org/docs/high-level-goals/)
https://webassembly.org/
[WASI: WebAssembly System Interface](https://github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime/blob/master/docs/WASI-overview.md)
[Features to add after the MVP](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/FutureFeatures.md)